# How can I increase font size in Spotlight

Tags: spotlight, font, accessibility

When I write 7/3 in spotlight it automatically shows result but the font is too small and doesn't have enough contrast. Is there a way to increase the size of the result font or all Spotlight fonts in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but once you enter an equation such as 7/3 in Spotlight and pause for a moment, it'll also preview the result below right of the search field:

[image]

You can also press <kbd>return</kbd> to display the result in the Calculator:

[image: Calculator]